# Elasticsearch request optimisation (strange script_score in Java API with bool query)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

With Elasticsearch 1.7.0, I'd like to make a query on a text field of my documents. I need to get all the documents which:

1. match partially (all the word needs to exist with synonyms et fuzzy)
2. match fuzzy (all the word needs to exist + fuzzy + phonetic)
3. match related (50% of the word need to be found)

I made a Java program with 3 Elasticsearch requests but those queries were too long so I've tried to use one query for all that:

```
{
  "query": 
    {"bool": {
      "should": [
        {
              "function_score": {
              "boost_mode": "replace",
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "text.syn": {
                    "query": "sorbone",
                    "operator": "and",
                    "fuzziness": 1,
                    "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                  }
                }
              },
              "script_score": {
                "script": "1"
              }
          }
        },
        {
              "function_score": {
              "boost_mode": "replace",
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "text.phonetic": {
                    "query": "sorbone",
                    "operator": "and",
                    "fuzziness": 1,
                    "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                  }
                }
              },
              "script_score": {
                "script": "3"
              }
          }
        },
        {
              "function_score": {
              "boost_mode": "replace",
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "text.phonetic": {
                    "query": "sorbone",
                    "operator": "or",                    
                    "minimum_should_match": "50%"
                  }
                }
              },
              "script_score": {
                "script": "7"
              }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to use a bool_query with a specific score for each document returned. It works well but when I try to convert it using Java API, I have a score strangely calculated, instead there are decimals in the score and I was waiting to have numbers like 7 3 1 4 10 8 which correspond to sum of score.

The code I used:

```
            .operator(org.elasticsearch.index.query.MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.AND)
            .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE)
            .minimumShouldMatch("100%");
    QueryBuilder termsPhon = matchQuery("text.phonetic", "sorbonne")
            .operator(org.elasticsearch.index.query.MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.AND)
            .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE)
            .minimumShouldMatch("100%");
    QueryBuilder termsText = matchQuery("text", "sorbonne")
            .operator(org.elasticsearch.index.query.MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.OR)
            .minimumShouldMatch("50%");
    QueryBuilder functionScorePartial = functionScoreQuery(termsSyn)
            .add(ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction("1"))
            .boostMode("replace");    


QueryBuilder functionScoreFuzzy = functionScoreQuery(termsPhon)
        .add(ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction("7"))
        .boostMode("replace");    

QueryBuilder functionScoreRelated = functionScoreQuery(termsText)
        .add(ScoreFunctionBuilders.scriptFunction("15"))
        .boostMode("replace")
        ;    

QueryBuilder boolQ = boolQuery()
        .should(functionScorePartial)
        .should(functionScoreFuzzy)
        .should(functionScoreRelated);

sqb.setQuery(boolQ);


SearchResponse response = sqb.execute().actionGet();
SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
```

When I look to the generated JSON I see that the script function is not generated the same way. In the original REST I've got:

```
"functions" : [ {
      "script_score" : {
        "script" : "1"
      }
    } ],
    "boost_mode" : "replace"
```

In the generated JSON, there's no "functions" array:

```
 "script_score": {
            "script": "1"
 }
```

Is it a bug in the Elasticsearch Java API?

Answer (score 1):

The `match` query is returning a decimal score based on the [Lucene scoring formula (TF-IDF ish)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html) for each matching query — which *then* gets multiplied by the boost you provided in your query.

> This actually can work to your advantage when the query contains
>   multiple matching terms (or when multiple expanded terms match).

---

For the simpler scoring strategy you're implementing, you need to use [Constant Score Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html)  to wrap filters inside your bool query.   This will allow you to return a *constant score* for each matching condition.

---

*Update*:  Even using Constant Score Queries, OP did not see expected scores out of the `bool` query due to query normalization.  The original idea with `function_score` query was on the right track (for implementing fully custom scoring), but also suffered from query normalization via the outer `bool` query.

The way to avoid this normalization is to make the `function_score` query the outermost query (and make the three matching conditions your scoring functions):

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "text.syn": {
                  "query": "sorbone",
                  "operator": "and",
                  "fuzziness": 1,
                  "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                }
              }
            }
          }, {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "text.phonetic": {
                  "query": "sorbone",
                  "operator": "or",
                  "minimum_should_match": "50%"
                }
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      },
      "functions": [{
        "filter": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "text.syn": {
                "query": "sorbone",
                "operator": "and",
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "minimum_should_match": "100%"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "weight": 1
      }, {
        "filter": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "text.phonetic": {
                "query": "sorbone",
                "operator": "and",
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "minimum_should_match": "100%"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "weight": 3
      }, {
        "filter": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "text.phonetic": {
                "query": "sorbone",
                "operator": "or",
                "minimum_should_match": "50%"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "weight": 7
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

*Note that 2 of the 3 matching criteria are also used as the initial `filter` clause for the `function_score` query so that the entire collection need not be scored.  (One criterion was omitted as redundant for filtering – since 100% of phonetic terms matching is a subset of 50% phonetic terms matching)*

Comment: Using this code with the use of constantScoreQuery gives me again floating number for the score :(

>    QueryBuilder boolQ = boolQuery()
>    .should(constantScoreQuery(termsSyn).boost(1))   
>    .should(constantScoreQuery(termsPhon).boost(7))
>    .should(constantScoreQuery(termsText).boost(15));       
>    sqb.setQuery(boolQ);

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works with this query, but do you know how to convert the functions [{...}] block with JavaApi ?

Comment: `FunctionScoreQueryBuilder` can take an array of `FilterFunctionBuilder`s in the constructor:   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/functionscore/FunctionScoreQueryBuilder.java

Answer (score 0):

Using this code with the use of constantScoreQuery gives me again floating number for the score :(

> QueryBuilder boolQ = boolQuery()
>      .should(constantScoreQuery(termsSyn).boost(1))
>      .should(constantScoreQuery(termsPhon).boost(7))
>      .should(constantScoreQuery(termsText).boost(15));
>      sqb.setQuery(boolQ);

Comment: I was awaiting to have scores of 1 or 7 or 15

Comment: Please post the full json query that is generated.